# Quarkus with Azure Text to Speech issue - Cognitive Services

Tags: quarkus, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Microsoft Cognitive Services within a Quarkus application. Everything works fine locally... including in a local Docker environment.
However when I deploy this thing to AKS... it logs the following error:

```
    f506c46e-0234-4dc6-a3c8-27d6949cd4b1-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.setTempDirectory(java.lang.String)'
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:138)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:503)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2442)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1476)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.setTempDirectory(java.lang.String)'
    at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.setTempDirectory(Native Method)
    at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.<clinit>(SpeechConfig.java:77)
```

I have checked the content of the tmp directory within the pod... and the files are created there... could this be due to the standard OS image that is added as part of a Quarkus container image?
For reference:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.3

ARG JAVA_PACKAGE=java-11-openjdk-headless
```

Content of PODs tmp:

```
/work # ls -ltr /tmp
total 84
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug  3 12:10 hsperfdata_root
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 Aug  3 12:10 vertx-cache
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3839 Aug  3 12:20 m4j3821112471677595333.tmp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         68372 Aug  3 12:20 m4j3337239382403748465.tmp
drwx------    2 root     root          4096 Aug  3 12:20 speech-sdk-native-15500065335689334576
```

Azure dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech</groupId>
      <artifactId>client-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Not sure what is causing this error. Did anyone experience this behaviour before?

Comment: This issue generally related to native libraries, what is happening is that the library that is using the image on the aks contains a library which has a different method signature than the one that was used to compile the application. I don't think that this has nothingto do with quarkus itself or the base image, because if is running ok locally it should run ok on aks, check your ci, to see if the building process is using something different. Or check the dependencies of the microsoft-sdk to see if might be something there

Comment: It is using the same java version in the CI. It really seems to be something with ubi8 minimal. It might not be supported by Microsoft Cognitive Services.

Comment: You can change de base image at any moment in the Dockerfiles or if you are using the container extensions, job or docker it is possible to use another different from the base one, I tend to use the adoptopenjdk as base-image. But if it work in your locak machine ..., and you are testing the docker itself, its rather unusual. I mean it is supposed to be the same artifact. Or maybe you are testing locally the jar itself and not the image ?